# Python Windows Wallpaper

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, wallpaper

I found following command to set the Desktop Wallpaper of Windows using Python:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(0x14, 0, 'C:\somepic.jpg', 0)
```

Unfortunately the Wallpaper isn't changed as I expected.

Am I missing something? Or is there another way to (permanently) change the Windows Wallpaper?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Found this solution:

```
cmd = "REG ADD \"HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d D:\30-10-2013.jpg" #changes the Registry Key "Wallpaper"
subprocess.call(cmd) 
subprocess.call("rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters") #To update the Wallpaper
```

**Problem:**
By checking the Registry entry you see, that Python messes something up with the **encoding**, because it removes the *\30* and replaces it with a little box (like [] ).

(It works by inserting these commands in a the Windows run-dialoge.)

**How to solve this encoding problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me say that I was not able to test if setting the Wallpaper was possible, since I do not use Windows myself.

As you can see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) `\30` is an escaped sequence with octal value resolving to `\x18` and therefore the none printable cancel character. Be sure to escape backslashes like `\\` anytime when used in strings.

For the first part of the question try using the Unicode version of the function so that *ctypes* passes the right data type since in Python 3 the String type [changed](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(0x14, 0, 'C:\\somepic.jpg', 0)
```